# Thread still runnng after destroying the the Activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I have destroyed my activity by calling finish().But the thread in the activity is still running after destroying the activity and it causes application crash..
How can I handle this?Why the thread runs after destroying the activity?
Please provide some help?

```
class DBThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (finish) {
            Cursor cursor = null;

            Cursor mCursor = lrDB.selectUserDetails(mUser_Id);
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                mCursor.moveToNext();
                String Name = mCursor .getString(0);
                String userName = mCursor .getInt(1);
                String password = mCursor .getString(3);

            }
            mCursor.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `ExecutorService` instead of a `Thread`, it's nicer. It has a `shutdown` and awaitTermination methods

Comment: The thread keeps running because it's its own little process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First correct your thread:

```
class DBThread extends Thread { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            Cursor mCursor = lrDB.selectUserDetails(mUser_Id); 
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) { 
                mCursor.moveToNext(); 
                String Name = mCursor .getString(0); 
                String userName = mCursor .getInt(1); 
                String password = mCursor .getString(3); 

            } 
            mCursor.close(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Secondly to close thread gracefuly do something like that in activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (yourThread!=null) {
        yourThread.interrupt(); // request to terminate thread in regular way
        yourThread.join(500); // wait until thread ends or timeout after 0.5 second
        if (yourThread.isAlive()) {
            // this is needed only when something is wrong with thread, for example hangs in ininitive loop or waits to long for lock to be released by other thread.
            Log.e(TAG, "Serious problem with thread!");
            yourThread.stop();
        }
    }
    super.onDrestroy();
}
```

Note that Thread.destroy() is deprecated and will not work.

Comment: Thread.stop() is also deprecated.So avoided that loop and it is worked.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thread.stop() yes it is deprecated since it can brake state of virtual machine, so it should be use only as last resort and this is what my code do and that is why my code logs an error.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` stop runs when it exit the `run` method. So, if you have a pattern like

```
public void run() {
  while(condition) {
    // exec
  }
}
```

remeber to set `condition` to `false`, in order to let thread finish its execution

```
class DBThread extends Thread {

private boolean finish = true;    

public void stopThread() {
   finish = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (finish) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        Cursor mCursor = lrDB.selectUserDetails(mUser_Id);
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mCursor.moveToNext();
            String Name = mCursor .getString(0);
            String userName = mCursor .getInt(1);
            String password = mCursor .getString(3);

        }
        mCursor.close();

    }
 }
}
```

The inside the `onDrestroy()` call `yourThreadInstance.stopThread();`

Comment: I have done it already but the thread runs..If activity is destroyed at the middle of thread execution what will do?

Comment: you can provide exit point inside the run. Just rember to set the exit condition when you leave the activity. If it does not work, means that the issue is related to something else

Comment: Added the code. In OnDestroy of activity I have called lrDB.close() to close database connection.And after closing the db it tries to query db.I have also added mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); as first statement in the selectUserDetails() function.

Comment: where do you set finish to false?

Answer (score 1):

add the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        thread.stop();
        thread.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this situation in onStop or onDestroy method. in onDestroy method interrupt the thread.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @Override     
> protected void onStop() {
>          thread.stop();
>            super.onDestroy();
>  }
>
>
>  @Override     
> protected void onPouse() {
>          thread.stop();
>         super.onDestroy();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can call interrupt function of the running thread and verify on the thread if you were interrupted using the isInterrupted() function and continue accordingly.